# Error when setting up Tab Navigator - ' Got an invalid Value for 'component' prop for screen 'Home'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm currently receiving the error 'Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Home'. It must be a valid React Component.'' I'm trying to link the tab navigator to a series of different screens. Please see the code below and thanks in advance. I'm a beginner clearly lol

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import HomePage from './Screen/Home'
import FuturePage from './Screen/Future'

const Tabs=createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App (){

    return (  
      <NavigationContainer>
       <Tabs.Navigator>
        <Tabs.Screen name='Home' component={HomePage} />
         <Tabs.Screen name='Future' component={FuturePage} />
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
```

Home Page Screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import {    AppRegistry, 
            View, 
            Text,
            ScrollView, 
            Image, 
            StyleSheet, 
            ImageBackground, 
            Animated, Easing
        } from 'react-native';

        export default class HomePage extends React.Component {

          render() {
return(
    <View style={styles.container}> 

    <ScrollView>
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 600}, {left: 25} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 950}, {left: 200} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 1200}, {left: 600} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 600}, {left: 700} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 1400}, {left: 250} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 950}, {left: 900} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 1500}, {left: 1000} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 1100}, {left: 1300} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 400}, {left: 1200} ]}
        />
         <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 1650}, {left: 650} ]}
        />
        <View
        style={[styles.tbcViews, {top: 1750}, {left: 75} ]}
        />


        <Image style={{resizeMode: 'repeat', height:2000, width:1500}}
        source={require('./assets/CurtainBG.png')}
        />


        </ScrollView>

         <Image
        style={styles.logo_title}
        source={require('./assets/Logo_Title.png')} 
        />  
        <Text
        style={styles.mini_titles}>FUTURE</Text>
        <Text
        style={styles.mini_titles2}>PAST</Text>
        <Icon 
        style={styles.arrows}
        name="ios-arrow-up" size={20} />
         <Icon 
        style={styles.arrowdown}
        name="ios-arrow-down" size={20} />
        <Image
        style={styles.futureicon}
        source={require('./assets/FutureIconBlue.png')} 
        />  
      </View>
);
};
        }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 500,
        width:  450,
        left: -25

    },
    logo_title: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        top:400,
        zIndex: 10,
        width: 450,
        height: 150,
      },
      mini_titles: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 12,
        top: 350,

      },
      mini_titles2: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 12,
        top: 550,

      },
      arrows: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 12,
        top: 300,

      },
      arrowdown: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 12,
        top: 600,

      },
      futureicon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 12,
        top: 85,
        height: 190,
        width: 190


      },

      tbcViews: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: 10,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        borderWidth:2.5,
        borderStyle: 'dotted',
        borderColor:'rgb(27, 63, 143)',
        borderRadius: 10
      },

})
```

Comment: Can you share the code for HomePage component ?

Comment: your HomePage component should export default HomePage; at the end of your file for the import to work

Comment: Please see the edited code above including the homepage code, Thanks

Comment: @DanielM have you had the chance to check out any of the answers below?

Answer (score 15):

It can also happen if you are not exporting your component

check the following

```js
export default HomePage
```

Answer (score 13):

I had exactly the same problem. After working a whole day on this, I found out that you can pass in components like `class MyComponent extends React.Component` or `const MyComponent = ({ param1, paramX}) => {}` by using the attribute `children`. First I was using the attribute `component={MyComponent}` for the component and `initalParams={...}` for passing params but now it looks like this:

```
<MyTabStack.Screen
      name={item.name.toString()}
      listeners={{ focus: () => setActiveTab(index) }}
      children={() => (
        <MyComponent
          data={allResults}
          sessionid={item.sessionid}
          name={item.name.toString()}
        />
      )}
      key={item.sessionid}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure HomePage is a right component. You can try by this

> `export default function App (){
>       return (
>
>         <HomePage/>
>           );
>       }`

Answer (score 1):

For each individual component that you're importing into app.js ensure that you're not exporting the component with a semi-colon at the end.

That solved my immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const HomeStack = () => {

    return (
            <Stack.Navigator headerMode = {'none'}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
    )
};

const ProfileStack = () => {

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode={'none'}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
};

const SettingsStack = () => {

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode={'none'}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
};

export default { HomeStack, ProfileStack, SettingsStack };
```

When I export multiple components it gives that error - but when I export just one component like :

```
export default HomeStack;
```

it works just fine - now I'm creating separate .js for every component lets see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This occured with me too.
In my case, I fixed it by **disabling minification in React Native DevMenu**.
Press `d` in the console where you started metro.
Go to Settings > JS Minify and uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import AuthStack from "./Src/Navigation/AuthStack";
import BottomNavBar from "./Src/Navigation/BottomNavBar";
    
const MainNav = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <MainNav.Navigator>
        <MainNav.Screen name="AuthStack" component={AuthStack} />
        <MainNav.Screen name="BottomNavBar" component={BottomNavBar} />
        </MainNav.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);}
```

In my case, it was just that I put `component={ < AuthStack/>}`, but in reality, it should be `component={AuthStack}`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u save the file from where the component is running

Answer (score 0):

I have just started learning React Native, and I ended up with same problem. None of the above suggestions work.
The interesting part of my problem is that I forget to "save" the `HomePage.js` file after making the necessary changes.

So, pls just ensure the changes are saved in each file.

Comment: This is just general advice. It's not really related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the `name` and `component` of the `Stack.Screen` component must be the same. This is what worked for me.

```
const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ContactsScreen"
          component={ContactsScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Contacts' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ContactDetailScreen"
          component={ContactDetailScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```